# How to retrieve phone number from Contacts framework

Tags: swift, contacts

New to contacts trying to retrieve Mobile Phone number. I have address name email but cannot figure out mobile phone. This is what I got. The portion marked with `**` is where I am going wrong.

```
if let oldContact = self.contactItem {
    let store = CNContactStore()

    do {
        let mykeysToFetch = [CNContactFormatter.descriptorForRequiredKeysForStyle(.FullName), CNContactEmailAddressesKey, CNContactPostalAddressesKey,CNContactImageDataKey, CNContactImageDataAvailableKey,CNContactPhoneNumbersKey]
        let contact = try store.unifiedContactWithIdentifier(oldContact.identifier, keysToFetch: mykeysToFetch)

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
            if contact.imageDataAvailable {
                if let data = contact.imageData {
                    self.contactImage.image = UIImage(data: data)
                }
            }

            self.fullName.text = CNContactFormatter().stringFromContact(contact)
            self.email.text = contact.emailAddresses.first?.value as? String
            self.phoneNumber.text = contact.phoneNumbers.first?.value as? String

            **if contact.isKeyAvailable(CNContactPhoneNumbersKey){
                if let phoneNum = contact.phoneNumbers.first?.value as? String {
                    self.phoneNumber.text = phoneNum as String
                }

            }**

            if contact.isKeyAvailable(CNContactPostalAddressesKey) {
                if let postalAddress = contact.postalAddresses.first?.value as? CNPostalAddress {
                    self.address.text = CNPostalAddressFormatter().stringFromPostalAddress(postalAddress)
                } else {
                    self.address.text = "No Address"
                }
            }
        })
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

If you want a list of the mobile phones for a contact, you look at `phoneNumbers` which is an array of `CNLabeledValue`, and find those with a `label` of `CNLabelPhoneNumberMobile` or `CNLabelPhoneNumberiPhone`.

For example, you could do something like:

```
let mobilePhoneLabels = Set<String>(arrayLiteral: CNLabelPhoneNumberMobile, CNLabelPhoneNumberiPhone, "cell", "mobile") // use whatever you want here; you might want to include a few strings like shown here to catch any common custom permutations user may have used

let mobileNumbers = contact.phoneNumbers.filter { mobilePhoneLabels.contains($0.label) && $0.value is CNPhoneNumber }
    .map { ($0.value as! CNPhoneNumber).stringValue }
```

So if you want the first one:

```
let mobileNumber = mobileNumbers.first ?? ""   // or use `if let` syntax
```

Or if you want a string representation of the list of them:

```
let mobileNumberString = mobileNumbers.joinWithSeparator(" ; ")
```

What you do with this array of mobile numbers is up to you, but hopefully this illustrates the basic idea.

Comment: what is the difference between label and CNLabeledValue ?

Comment: A `CNLabeledValue` is an object that consists of a `label` (e.g. "home", "work", "mobile", etc.; these are generally codified using the `CNLabelPhoneNumber...` constants to maximize localization compatibility, though they can consist of simple strings, too) and a `value` (the `CNPhoneNumber` of the number itself). See https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Contacts/Reference/CNLabeledValue_Class/index.html.